# Switching from IBM MQ to Tibco EMS

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, tibco-ems

We are creating new application, which is going to use IBM's MQ as a JMS provider for a short term and switch to Tibco EMS within a year.
My question is how involving the changes would be from the Application code perspective.

So far reading from JMS documentation, my impression is it should only require minimal changes. Does anyone have experience with it and provide some input on the work involved in switching between JMS provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done POCs where I swapped out connection factories and used WMQ JMS Classes to send to various providers (TIBCO, ActiveMQ, etc), to prove out the interchangeability.  I've also done full swaps from one vendors JMS to another.  In theory, it should be very simple.

The biggest change will be with the connection factories.  Everything JMS specific will be the same between providers. The more tightly coupled the code is to the connection factories, the more complex it will be to change the app itself.  Outside of this, you may need to change vendor specific implementation of objects, such as MQQueue vs Queue.

One addition thing to keep in mid is dependent on the IBM endpoints.  If you are using "target queue managers" on any producers, these will need to change.  WMQ has a specific URI to reach queues on specific Queue Managers in a cluster ( "queue://target_qm/queue_name/" ).  If any application uses this URI it will need to ensure it makes the proper changes here as well.